# API Post request to sanity patch query takes upwards of 2 seconds to complete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, sanity, groq

I'm struggling to understand what could be causing a slow response from the server, upwards of 2 seconds for a simple patch. I've gone ahead and posted an example to help better illustrate the problem. Right now if you swipe right on a card, it will kick off a saveLike and saveVote. Both will fetch data from Card.js about what card you swiped right on and your userID to save to. I'm running next.js with sanity.io, using yarn dev and yarn start respectively. Even insight on how to debug what could be causing a long wait period for a query would be super helpful long term

**#context**

```
const handleRightSwipe = async (cardData, votesData) => {

    try {

      await fetch('/api/saveLike', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body:  JSON.stringify({
          likedCards: cardData,
          currentUser: "abc123",
        }),

      })
      // deduct one incrementally 
      let votesAmount = votesData--
      try {
        await fetch('/api/saveVote', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body:  JSON.stringify({
          _id: "abc123",
          votes: votesAmount
        }),
      })

    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
      // set vote tally the latest amount
      setVotesData(votesAmount)
      // request vote tally be updated on the client side
      requestVoteAmount(userID)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }
```

**# saveVote**

```
import { client } from '../../lib/sanity'

const saveVote = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await client
      .patch(req.body._id).set({votes:req.body.votes}).commit()
    res.status(200).send({ message: 'success' })
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send({ message: 'error', data: error.message })
  }
}

export default saveVote
```

**#saveLike**

```
import { client } from '../../lib/sanity'

const saveLike = async (req, res) => {

  try {

    await client
      .patch(req.body.likedCards._id)
      .setIfMissing({'likes': []})
      .insert('after', 'likes[-1]',[
        {
          _ref: req.body.currentUser,
          _type: "reference",
        },
      ])
      .commit({
        autoGenerateArrayKeys: true,
      })

    res.status(200).send({ message: 'success' })
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send({ message: 'error', data: error.message })
  }

}
```

**#Card**

```
import React, { useState, useMemo, useContext, useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Context} from '../context/Context'
import TCard from 'react-tinder-card'

const Card = () => {

  const { cardsData, votesData } = useContext(Context)
  const { handleRightSwipe, handleLeftSwipe, currentAccountAddress } = useContext(Context)
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(cardsData.length - 1)
  const currentIndexRef = useRef(currentIndex)
  const childRefs = useMemo(
    () =>
      Array(cardsData.length)
        .fill(0)
        .map((i) => React.createRef()),
    [cardsData.length]
  )

  const updateCurrentIndex = (val) => {
    setCurrentIndex(val)
    currentIndexRef.current = val
  }
const canVote = votesData > 0
const swiped = (direction, card, index) => {
  if (!canVote) return
  if (votesData > 0) {
    if (direction === 'right') {
      const voterAmount = votesData--
      updateCurrentIndex(index - 1)
      handleRightSwipe(card, currentAccountAddress, voterAmount)
    }
    if (direction === 'left') {
      const voterAmount = votesData--
      updateCurrentIndex(index - 1)
      handleLeftSwipe(card, currentAccountAddress, voterAmount)
    }
  }
  else {
  }
}
const outOfFrame = (idx) => {
  currentIndexRef.current >= idx && childRefs[idx].current.restoreCard()
}
  return (
    <div>
      {
        <div>
        {cardsData.map((card, index) => (
          <TCard 
            card={card}
            key={card.name}
            ref={childRefs[index]}
            preventSwipe={['up', 'down']}
            onCardLeftScreen={() => outOfFrame(card.name, index)}
            onSwipe={(dir) => swiped(dir, card, index)}>
              <div
              style={{ backgroundImage: `url('${card.imageUrl}')` 
           >
              </div>
          </TCard> ))}
        </div>
      }
    </div>    
  )
}
export default Card
```